# Accessing property of an Ajax response in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a following issue using this code:

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(Config.rootUrl, {
        params
    }).subscribe(response => {
        resolve(response.data);
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
    });
});
```

Now PhpStorm, the IDE I use, reports the line `resolve( response.data );` with an error:

> property data does not exist on type Object

I would not care that much about it but sometimes, sometimes, after compilation Angular reports the same problem.

Does anyone can tell me what the issue is here?

Regards,
Radek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the overload of `http.get` that specifies the type parameter to return a strongly typed object, ie:

`export interface MyInterface.....`

`this.http.get<MyInterface>().subscribe(res => ....)`

res would be of type `MyInterface` with whatever properties you have defined.

Comment: Thank you very much